# Ansible - passing a var if it exists

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-role

I am running an ansible playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory1.yml playbooks/playbook1.yml 
    --extra-vars "environment=my_env var=my_var"
```

My inventory1.yml looks like this:

```
    ...
      children:
        env1:
          hosts:
            env1.domain.com:
          vars:
            port: '8000'
            name: name1
            parameter: 'parameter1'
        env2:
          hosts:
            env2.domain.com:
          vars:
            port: '8000'
            name: name2
        env3:
          hosts:
            env3.domain.com:
          vars:
            port: '8000'
            name: name3
            parameter: 'parameter1'
```

Note: Parameter only exists in some envs (env1 and env3).

My playbook1.yml:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ environment }}"

  roles:
   - my_role
```

### My_role (main.yml):

```
- name: My_role
  command: ansible-playbook
    -i inventory/inventory2.yml playbook2.yml
    --extra-vars="
    environment={{ environment }}
    parameter={{ parameter }}
    "
```

As you can see I am using a playbook (playbook1.yml) to run second playbook(playbook2.yml),
and I am using some vars from inventory1.yml when I am running playbook2.yml.

As I only have the variable "parameter" in some environments (env1 and env3) I want to pass the variable if it exists (in the --extra-vars). If it doesn't exist, I don't want to pass it (nor can I pass it).

How can I do this in the main.yml (in my_role) ?
Is there any condition or any statement that I can use for this?

Comment: => `ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'toto=' ~ toto if toto is defined }}"` and for a "positive" example => `ansible localhost -m debug -e "toto=test" -a "msg={{ 'toto=' ~ toto if toto is defined }}"`

Comment: I tried but I am getting this error: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: the inline if-expression on line 1 evaluated to false and no else section was defined."

Comment: Please upgrade ansible and jinja2 to recent supported versions.

Comment: Using ansible 2.10.15. SHould be enough for this

Comment: Or just defining an 'else' block is enough (refer my udpated answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I have achieved the similar thing in the past was using if else construct:

```
- name: My_role
  command: ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory2.yml playbook2.yml --extra-vars="environment={{ environment }} {{ 'parameter='~parameter if parameter is defined }}"
```

As per your requirement, you can change the if conditions:

> "parameter is defined" - check for declaration
> "parameter | length > 0" - check for non-emptiness

Let me know if that works for you, look for syntax error if you get due to quotes.

**Edited**

Forgot about the case where parameter is not defined, 'else' was must.
`[[ in latest version of ansible 'else' is not necessary, I have tested it on 2.13.1 ]]`

```
- name: My_role
  command: ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory2.yml playbook2.yml --extra-vars="environment={{ environment }} {{ 'parameter='~parameter if parameter is defined else '' }}"
```

Comment: I am trying but I am getting some syntax error.
"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: the inline if-expression on line 1 evaluated to false and no else section was defined."
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory2.yml playbook2.yml --extra-vars=" environment={{ environment }} {{'parameter=' ~ parameter if parameter is defined }}. 
Is this the sintax or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried defining the variable parameter and it works. So basically what is happening it that ansible doesn't know what to do if the var is not defined. So something is missing I guess... Any thoughts please?

Comment: Just updated the answer. Yes, else was needed if 'if' condition fails.